# Angular ide cannot unpack from zip, due to too long paths

Tags: windows, path, zip

I've wanted to learn more angular development for a while now, So I was excited for the release of an integrated angular ide, based on eclipse technology, yesterday 4th of january.

link https://www.genuitec.com/products/angular-ide/download/

But I can't make it work properly. When trying to unzip the pack, the folder structure and path name is too long for windows 7 to handle. I put the zip in a direct subfolder of C.-drive, to allow for as long path as possible, but it still doesn't work. The problematic path is

```
C:\angular\angularide.zip\angular-ide\plugins\ternjs_1.2.0.201701041527\node_modules\tern-eslint\node_modules\eslint\node_modules\file-entry-cache\node_modules\flat-cache\node_modules\del\node_modules\rimraf\node_modules\glob\node_modules\minimatch\node_modules\brace-expansion\
```

..and all subfolders of it, which is three more levels or so.

THis download is specifically for windows. Am I not understanding how to unpack this, or is it a bug in the package?

The system runs even if I skip those folders and files, but I do not know the extent of the missing files, and would like to do it right.

Comment: No repro: Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit / NTFS formatted drive -  extracted successfully using 7zip

Comment: @DavidPostill, thanks a lot. It actually really helps to hear that you didn't have the same problem. I'll try again on another computer